# Animating Repeater Item Height In NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to remove an item from a Repeater in NativeScript by simply collapsing it. I can scale the item's height just fine, but the space is preserved so that the Repeater jumps up after the item is removed. I want the remaining items in the Repeater to move up as the item being remove is collapsed.

Here is the behaviour I have now. Notice that the rest of the items don't move until the item being deleted is finished animating.

[image]

Here is what I've got so far for the animation code:

```
let remove = (args: EventData) => {
    let view = <View>args.object;
    let item = view.parent.parent;

    let todo = view.bindingContext;

    item.originY = 0;

    item.animate({
        scale: { x: 1, y: 0 },
        curve: "easeIn",
        duration: 500
    })
    .then(() => {
        item.visibility = 'collapsed';
        viewModel.remove(todo);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to animate the repeater view itself up at the same time with multi-view animations?

http://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/ui/animation/HOW-TO#animating-multiple-views-simultaneously

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that you don't know which item in the Repeater is going to be deleted. Further, if you have items that are outside the structure of the Repeater that also need to move up, you need to select the entire parent to do that. It gets really icky really fast. NativeScript also doesn't offer a selector that says "get me all the siblings of this item that come after this item".

Answer (score 0):

What about yank the repeater and replace it with the new (free) RadListView which has this added by default, very smooth

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/ListView/item-animations

Comment: That's a good solution. If I can't find one for the stock listview, I may go with that option instead. Still looking for the technical answer here though... :)